# Display product title on image hover

Tags: css, shopify, mousehover

I've been trying to get our product titles to appear when you hover over the product image in a contained box at the overlays on the bottom portion of the image. We're trying to achieve this rather than have the product title and price appear below the image itself.

I tried this css code that was recomendded by Shopify but it didn't do anything:

```
 <noscript>
    {% capture product_image_size %}{{ height }}x{% endcapture %}
    <div class="reveal">
    <img src="{{ featured_media | img_url: product_image_size, scale: product_image_scale }}" alt="{{ featured_media.alt }}" id="FeaturedMedia-{{ section.id }}" class="product-featured-media" style="max-width: {{ height }}px;">
       <div class="hidden">
       <div class="caption">
       <div class="centered">
       <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
       <p>{{ product.price | money }}</p>
       </div><!-- end of .centered -->
          </div><!-- end of .caption -->
         </div><!-- end of .hidden -->
    </div>
      </noscript>
```

The css that exists for the current product title is just in terms of it's positioning seems to be:

```
  .grid--view-items {
    overflow: auto;
     margin-bottom: -35px; }

 .grid-view-item {
  margin: 0 auto 35px; }
  .custom__item .grid-view-item {
   margin-bottom: 0; }

 .grid-view-item__title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
   color: var(--color-text); }

.grid-view-item__meta {
 margin-top: 8px; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
  .grid-view-item__title,
  .grid-view-item__meta {
   font-size: calc(((var(--font-size-base) - 1) / (var(--font-size-base))) * 1em); } }

.grid-view-item__link {
 display: block; }

.grid-view-item__vendor {
   margin-top: 4px;
   color: var(--color-body-text);
   font-size: calc(((var(--font-size-base) - 2) / (var(--font-size-base))) * 1em);
   text-transform: uppercase; }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
     .grid-view-item__vendor {
     font-size: calc(((var(--font-size-base) - 3) / (var(--font-size-base))) * 1em); } }
```

If anyone has suggestions on how to get this done let me know!! The goal is to get the hover look similar to this site: https://www.lazyoaf.com/collections/men-new-in-1

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach you could use, I have kept your html structure as close to your original.

A tip for next time you ask a question, you may get an answer faster if you provide a live code snippet .i.e convert your php into static html etc..

```css
.reveal {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.reveal img {
  object-fit:cover;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.reveal:hover .hidden{
  opacity:1;
}
.hidden {
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  padding:1rem;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition:.8s ease;
  opacity:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
   
    <div class="reveal">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900/09f/fff.png" id="FeaturedMedia-{{ section.id }}" class="product-featured-media" style="max-width: {{ height }}px;">
       <div class="hidden">
       <div class="caption">
       <div class="centered">
       <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
       <p>{{ product.price | money }}</p>
       </div><!-- end of .centered -->
          </div><!-- end of .caption -->
         </div><!-- end of .hidden -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey Aaron! Is there any way to have this appear on all existing product images? Rather than a url to an image?